# ¿Para que se usa Maven? ¿Aun se usa?

Tags: java, java-ee, maven

Buen día, quisiera saber para que se usa Maven o las ventajas de utilizarlo si es que aun se usa.
Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola David, bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a que visites el __[tour]__ para que conozcas como funciona esta comunidad. Pero te puedo adelantar que las preguntas donde se piden opiniones, sugerencias o recomendaciones no son aceptadas, por lo que deben ser cerradas. Visita el [Centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para mayor información.

Comment: Hola @toledano, gracias por la bienvenida, con respecto a mi pregunta creo que no contiene sugerencias, opiniones ni recomendaciones, puesto que estoy preguntando el para que se usa una herramienta. 
Gracias.

Comment: David, por favor lee esta guía [__Qué tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar__](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las ventajas de maven son principalmente tres:

1. Todos los proyectos maven están estructurados igual. Si te cambias de un proyecto maven a otro, sabes automáticamente donde están los fuentes, como compilarlos, como generar el jar, etc, etc
2. maven te baja automáticamente de internet las librerías de las que dependes, te ahorras buscarlas y bajártelas a mano
3. Permite compilar el proyecto desde línea de comandos, por lo que es fácil automatizar una compilación en herramientas de integración contínua como jenkins.

Sí, maven se sigue usando. Ha reemplazado prácticamente del todo a otra herramienta similar más antigua que es ant. Pero actualmente está siendo a su vez desplazado por gradle.

Saludos.